# OnCreatView function of fragment called on previos fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

i found an example to use fragments without using tabBar
but now i founded that a fragment OnCreatView called on previos fragment and with this i haven't any control to lifecycle of fragment

this is my code

```
public class AddTextActivity AppCompatActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
public static FragmentManager frmanager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cordinate);


    frmanager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    initialisePaging();


}

private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frags.Addtext1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frags.Addtext2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Frags.Addtext3.class.getName()));


    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter1(frmanager, fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
}
```

and this is the pagerAdapter1

```
public class PagerAdapter1 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public PagerAdapter1(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

so now how can i prevent from calling onCreatView of next fragment ??

Comment: But why don't you want that the viewpager calls onCreateView-method next fragment? The fact is that is a feature of view pager, it creates current fragment and the fragments before and next

Comment: You should forced update fragment in OnPageChangeListener

Comment: thank u for answering. in a simple example i want to setVisibility of a button in a activity to invisible when i am in fragment1 and then when we going to next fragment setVisibility to Visible. exactly i want to know which fragment now is in sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For determine which page is selected:

```
   mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
           // TODO insert your code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: i done this but have a error

`pager.OnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()`

on pager have error: Expected class or package